# How to set Node,js server to answer requests from domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, dns, ip

I have a domain set up to point to my server at home, by way of the router's public IP. I am forwarding port 80 to my server from the router.

I have a node.js server running on the target machine but I cannot get it to answer using a loopback (setting it to listen on localhost). It will only answer http requests through the domain if it is set to listen on all addresses (0.0.0.0). This is undesirable for obvious reasons but I cannot seem to get it working as it should and no amount of googling seems to yield the answer.

Do I need to add a clause to my hosts file like this?
127.0.0.1    mydomain

Should I set the server to listen for the domain name?

I feel like I am forgetting something stupid and would really appreciate some assistance. Also, not to be rude but I am not using express or any third party module for this so info utilizing built-in node modules/standards will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to be accessible from a remote machine, you need to listen on an external interface. `0.0.0.0` is usually suitable unless you have multiple network interfaces and need to choose one ip only. Can you listen on a higher port and map it via your router?

Comment: Thank you for the good advice! I just had to use the local ip of the machine, which is actually a vm on a windows server (sorry, I should've included more details). I want to keep the ip of each server specific as I add more of them. I really appreciate the fast responses, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you starting the server in node? Are you specifying a host name? If not, it defaults to `0.0.0.0`

[HTTP - Node Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback)

`server.listen([port][, hostname])`

Adding the host entry as you mentioned may help, but can't confirm without knowing your exact setup.